# execute jar file from remote machine in java

Tags: java, jar

I have created a jar file.I copy this jar file into remote machine using ssh in java.

I want to execute this jar file from my machine and see the result in my machine.

```
java -jar <filename>
```

I use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar hellofile.jar");
```

Any suggesions ? Please answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote machine is linux, you can execute through ssh:

```
ssh remote@machine.com 'java -jar hellofile.jar'
```

and you will see the result in the terminal

Comment: ssh remote_username@remote_host 'java -jar hellofile.jar'

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file to execute java -jar hellofile.jar from remote cmd.

Now run the batch file from your local machine by PSEXEC \othermachine z:\program.exe. You will need administrator privileges on the target machine.

P.S: PSEXEC will wok only on windows

Comment: Linux equivalent would be something like `ssh user1@server1 'java -jar hellofile.jar'`