# run a jarfile in a different machine from an sqlserver/issue a terminal command from an sqlserver to another windows machine

Tags: java, sql-server, windows, stored-procedures, remote-access

I have a series of **stored procedures**(say, SP1, SP2, SP3) consecutively running on an **sqlserver**(say, serverA).

After SP3 finishes execution, I want to run a **jar** file in some machine (say, computerA). Is there a way for me to trigger the run of my jar file in computerA after SP3 finishes executing in serverA?

Note: I can only run my jar file in computerA because my jar file actually retrieves data from **Bloomberg API**. So, this jar file needs to run in a machine that has **Bloomberg terminal** on it. Only computerA has a Bloomberg terminal.

I think another way of saying this is how to issue a terminal command from an sqlserver to another windows machine. Because I can just issue the following command to computerA but I really don't know how to make that possible.

```
java -jar D:\Runnables\myJavaApp.jar
```

Comment: What are you using to execute the SPs?  SSIS, SSMS, etc?

Comment: The SPs are executed through an SQL Server Agent Job in SSMS.

Comment: You could wrap the command in a remote batch file, and execute that as an additional step in your job.  See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395168/execute-jar-file-from-remote-machine-in-java)  for more.

Comment: Hi @destination-data, PSExec runs well. However, I am just curious. Can I do it also using microsoft telnet?

Comment: Not sure. That isn't something I've tried.

Comment: Hi @destination-data, thank you very much! I'll also ask around regarding using microsoft telnet